# How to fetch images from JSON object if imagelink is given as string in android using java and display in listview using ArrayAdapters?

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to fetch image from JSONObject where imagelink is given as string. In the below code image link is fetched  as `JSONObject image = volumeInfo.getJSONObject("imageLinks"); String imagelink = image.getString("smallThumbnail");`

My Question is how to fetch images from a json given as string and display it on a listview using ArrayAdapters. Without using any volley or anyother library can we fetch images ?

My Api is:
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android&maxResults=1

My Extracting data method is:

```
        public static List<Books> extractFeatureFromJson(String bookjson) throws IOException, JSONException {
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(bookjson)){
        return  null;
    }

    //create a arraylist so that we can add new books to the list received from the json
    List<Books> books = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        String authorname = null;
        String title = null;
        JSONObject jsonObjectbase = new JSONObject(bookjson);
        JSONArray items = jsonObjectbase.getJSONArray("items");

        for(int i= 0; i<items.length(); i++){
            JSONObject firstjsonobj = items.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject volumeInfo = firstjsonobj.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
            JSONArray authorArray;


            if(volumeInfo.has("authors")) {
                authorArray = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
                authorname=authorArray.getString(0);
            }
            if(volumeInfo.has("title")) {
                title=volumeInfo.getString("title");
            }

            JSONObject image = volumeInfo.getJSONObject("imageLinks");
            String imagelink = image.getString("smallThumbnail");

            JSONObject location = firstjsonobj.getJSONObject("saleInfo");
            String country = location.getString("country");

                Books books1 = new Books(authorname, title, country, imagelink);
                books.add(books1);
            }
            Log.e("BOoksQuery", "Problem in fetching image23");
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
        // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
        // with the message from the exception.

    }
```

My Books.java class is:

```
package com.example.booklistingapp;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;

public class Books {
private String writer_name;
private  String book_name;
private String location;
 private String image;


public Books(String writer_name, String book_name, String location, String image) {
    this.writer_name = writer_name;
    this.book_name = book_name;
    this.location = location;
    this.image = image;
}

public String getWriter_name() {
    return writer_name;
}


public String getBook_name() {
    return book_name;
}


public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}
```

}

My ArrayAdapter is:

```
public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Books> {
public BookAdapter(@NonNull Activity context, ArrayList<Books> 
 books) {
    super(context, 0, books);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, 
  @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View listitemview = convertView;
    if(listitemview == null){
        listitemview = 


  LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).
  inflate(R.layout.activity_format, 
  parent,false);
    }

    Books books = getItem(position);


    TextView writer = (TextView) 
  listitemview.findViewById(R.id.writername);
    writer.setText(books.getWriter_name());

    TextView bookname = (TextView) 
  listitemview.findViewById(R.id.bookname);
    bookname.setText(books.getBook_name());

    TextView location = (TextView) 
   listitemview.findViewById(R.id.location);
    location.setText(books.getLocation());

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) 
 listitemview.findViewById(R.id.bookimage);
    
 
 
 
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(books.getImage()).into(imageView, 
  new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });


    return listitemview;

}
```

My Bookclass.java is:

```
  package com.example.booklistingapp;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.LinearLayout;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
```

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

```
 import org.json.JSONException;

 import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BookClass extends AppCompatActivity {
public  int Book_Loader_id = 1;
private  BookAdapter bookAdapter;
TextView textView;
private  static final  String BOOKS_URL = 
  "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=quilting";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.booklist);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String search = bundle.getString("Bookname");
    String url = bundle.getString("URL");



        ListView listView = (ListView) 
  findViewById(R.id.listview);
        TextView textView = (TextView) 
   findViewById(R.id.empty_list_textview);
        listView.setEmptyView(textView);

        bookAdapter = new BookAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Books> 
  ());
        listView.setAdapter(bookAdapter);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String apibook = BOOKS_URL;
        stringBuilder.append(apibook).append(search);
        String criteria = stringBuilder.toString();



        BookAsync bookAsync = new BookAsync();
        bookAsync.execute(criteria);

  }

  private class  BookAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, 
  List<Books>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Books> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        if (urls.length < 1 || urls[0] == null) {
            return null;
        }

        List<Books> books = null;
        try {
            books = BooksQuery.fetchbooklistdata(urls[0]);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("BookClass", "Threads in background is creating 
  a problem");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return books;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Books> data) {
        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            bookAdapter.addAll(data);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OkHttpClient to download image. But consider using Glide or Picasso when working with images.

- Consider using Kotlin instead of Java
- Consider using RecyclerView instead of ListView
- Consider using Kotlin Coroutine instead of AsyncTask